# What makes drupal different in terms of SEO than Joomla and which better?

Tags: drupal, seo, joomla

What makes drupal different in terms of SEO (search engine optimization) than Joomla and which better ?

Answer (score 0):

Neither one is better than the other for SEO. Both are capable of having source ordered content, custom meta tags, custom titles, and SEF URLs. As far as the search engines are concerned, Drupal and Joomla are indistinguishable.

The real question is which is easier to manipulate those items on. I use Joomla because it is easier to teach non-tech clients so I can only comment on that. We typically use K2, the core SEF URLs, and a custom template to control all of those things easily through the admin.

Answer (score 0):

Read this page and download the SEO PDF under the "Help Resources" header--a wealth of knowledge right from the horses mouth. Like Brent says, probably no difference between the two platforms.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has a lot of modules which are in fact very powerful and enterprise level. You can see an article comprehensively dealing with [Drupal SEO here](http://safwan.in/drupal/drupal-search-engine-optimization-seo-tip).